# Pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

This is not a duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

After consulting the previous question, I have another :

My problem is that when I get the php array in Js, and I print it, I have just [object][object]

```
<?php 
    $tl = array(
         0=>array('a', 'b', 1),
         1=>array('c', 'd', 2)
    ); 
?>
```

and javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr= <?php echo json_encode($tl ); ?>;

    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
        alert(arr[i]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: in place of alert, use console.log(arr[i]). It will print the actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should display it using `console.log` instead of alert :

```
console.log(arr[i]); //Check the result in you browser console
```

**console.log :** Formats your objects nicely and allows to traverse them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ...and OP will have to *open their Javascript console* too, otherwise not much will be shown...

Comment: Yes that true,(i have added that in comment) thanks for your intervention.

Answer (score 1):

**Remember**: 
You don't have more than 2 object in your array so you should not run loop more than 2 times.
first loop give you permission to access the object of array then you can run a loop to show/get the property of object.

```
 <?php 
   $tl = array(
      0=>array('a', 'b', 1),
      1=>array('c', 'd', 2)
  ); 
?>
```

var arr = ;

```
for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
        alert(arr[i][j]);
        console.log(arr[i][j]);// you can also show the value from the console of your browser
  }
}
```

output of console

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

> `alert()` shows type if not basic data type. In your case it's Object that's why it's showing [object][object]

To debug JavaScript one should use `console.log()` and other console methods like:

```
console.log();
console.debug();
console.warn();
console.error();
```

etc.

One more thing here you are trying to access values of nested array so you can go with alert like this:

```
var arr= <?php echo json_encode($tl ); ?>;
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    alert(arr[i][0] + " " + arr[i][1] + " " + arr[i][2]);
}
```

**OR**

Use nested loop to iterate inner array values;

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="array" value="<?php echo json_encode($tl); ?>" />
```

then use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = getElementById('array').value
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    alert(arr[i]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you want to to that when you already can access it directly?

Comment: i think is more easier and efficient that way